# How to strictly bound places within 15km of a particular LatLng in Google Places Autocomplete API?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am implementing Google Places Autocomplete API in Android. It should display only the places in the 15km radius of `LatLong 10.0158605,76.3418666`. The issue is, it will also display other places in India along with the places in this 15km radius. Is there any way to Strictly Bound only 15km places? I found codes in Javascript to give restriction and strictly bound. But I don't know how to solve it in Android. Please give a solution.

```
/* autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(
         {'location': '10.0158605,76.3418666',
         'radius':15});
         autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: true});  */ //JavaScript   


  private static final LatLng south=new LatLng(9.876752,76.483111);
  private static final LatLng north=new LatLng(10.141144,76.470065);
  private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW1=LatLngBounds.builder().include(north).include(south).build();

  location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                  .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
                    .setCountry("IN")
                    .build();
            try {

                Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder
                        (PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                        .setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW1)
                        .setFilter(typeFilter)
                        .build(getActivity());
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
                    GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please try this Github Google sample source: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places